# Update multiple fields based on multiple Criteria in one Query

Tags: sql-update

I am trying to update 3 different columns in a table based on 3 different conditions in the where clause. (I have the updated data in a different table, so I am joining them on the primary keys)

For example, if I did not have a value previously  in field1 for a customer but now I do,
I should be able to update the column 'field1'. Similarly, I would like to update columns field2 and field3.

Can I accomplish this in a single Update statement.

To Update one column you can write something like this:

```
Update tblCustomer 
SET tblCustomer.Order_Date = tblCustomerInfo.Order_Date
FROM tblCustomer 
LEFT JOIN tblCustomerInfo ON (tblCustomer.CustomerID = tblCustomerInfo.CustomerID)
WHERE tblCustomer.Order_Date <> tblCustomerInfo.Order_Date 
  AND tblCustomer.Order_Date is NULL;
```

How about updating 3 different Columns in single go based on different where conditions
(if the data was missing for that column was missing previously, and is now available)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
UPDATE categories
    SET display_order = CASE id
        WHEN 1 THEN 3
        WHEN 2 THEN 4
        WHEN 3 THEN 5
    END,
    title = CASE id
        WHEN 1 THEN 'New Title 1'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'New Title 2'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'New Title 3'
    END
WHERE id IN (1,2,3)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can update multiple columns

```
 UPDATE [t1]
  SET field1 = t2.field1,
      field2 = CASE WHEN <field 2 changed> THEN t2.field2 ELSE t1.field2 END,
      field3 = CASE WHEN t1.field3 <> t2.field3 THEN t2.field3 else t1.field3 END
  FROM <table1> as t1
  LEFT JOIN <table2> as t2 on t1.key1 = t2.key1
```